# Не работает функция permutations Ошибка:RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in compariso

Tags: python

Почему не работает?

```
from itertools import permutations

def permutations(string):
    if len(string)<2: return [string]
    else: return [''.join(x) for x in permutations(string)]
    

print(permutations("ab"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы вызываете рекурсивно функцию без изменения аргумента. Лучше не используйте идентификаторы, являющиеся названиями модулей/стандартных функций/ключевых слов.

```
import itertools

def permutations(string):
    if len(string)<2: return [string]
    else: return [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(string)]
    

print(permutations("ab"))
```